# Failed to parse query in elasticsearch and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, elasticsearch

So i am using this [library](https://github.com/confact/elasticsearch-codeigniter-library) for elastic search in codeigniter. and i want to return documents with size of 30

```
 public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->data;
        $query = '{
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "sch_id" : 45
                }
            }
        }';
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($data['elastic']->query_wresultSize('_search',$query,30));
        echo "</pre>";
        // return view('dashboard/dashboard',$data);
    }
```

But now it shows an error

```
["root_cause"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(21) "query_shard_exception"
        ["reason"]=>
        string(90) "Failed to parse query [{
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "sch_id" : 45
                }
            }
        }]"
        ["index_uuid"]=>
        string(22) "xbrATjiKR_uKtAGN3-GrRw"
        ["index"]=>
        string(7) "article"
      }
    }
```

```
["reason"]=>
          string(90) "Failed to parse query [{
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "sch_id" : 45
                }
            }
        }]"
          ["index_uuid"]=>
          string(22) "xbrATjiKR_uKtAGN3-GrRw"
          ["index"]=>
          string(7) "article"
          ["caused_by"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["type"]=>
            string(15) "parse_exception"
            ["reason"]=>
            string(170) "Cannot parse '{
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "sch_id" : 45
                }
            }
        }': Encountered "  ": "" at line 1, column 13.
Was expecting:
    "TO" ...
    "
```

i just don't know what am i doing wrong because i didn't use any reserved word in the query but it shows me the error above

can someone show me my mistake or tell me an alternative way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know how the query in this this [library](https://github.com/confact/elasticsearch-codeigniter-library) works. so i used Guzzle instead. Here is my solution for anyone having the same problem.

```
$uri = 'http://localhost:9200/article/_search/';

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $uri, [
                'headers' => [
                        'Accept' => 'application/json',
                        'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ],
                'body' => '{
                    "size" : 30,
                    "query" : {
                        "match" : {
                            "sch_id" : 45
                        }
                    }
                }',
            ]
        );

        $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```